# What are flutter_jank_metrics_<num>.json files in Flutter project?

Tags: flutter, dart, jank

What are flutter_jank_metrics_.json in Flutter project root folders?
Why & How they generated?
[image: the_files]

It might related to Flutter UI janky, but I don't see it on Flutter's official document.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For future me and people who are also curious.

The jank file are from the interacting-terminal after `flutter run`, you can press j to generate it.

> `j Dump frame raster stats for the current frame. (Unsupported for web)`

Detail about the file **might** related to: https://docs.flutter.dev/perf/ui-performance